# Newtonsoft.Json nuget error, some references do not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I need help every time I try to use some Newtonsoft.Json configuration, an error appears:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
Error CS0433 The type "JObject" exists in "Newtonsoft.Json, Version = 6.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version = 12.0.0.0, Culture = neutral,
PublicKeyToken = 30ad4fe6b2a6aeed "mia C: \ Users \ Wesley \ source \ repos \ mia2 \ mia \ Controllers \ Api \ ContaController.cs 18 Active
```

I've already reinstalled my Nuget packages several times and it doesn't work and it's only in this application that I'm having this problem

Example of my controller

```
public IHttpActionResult Login (JObject form)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var email = string.Empty;
        var password = string.Empty;

        dynamic JsonObject = form;

        try
        {
            email = JsonObject.Email.Value;
            password = JsonObject.Password.Value;
        }
        catch
        {

            return BadRequest("chamada Incorreta, Campo Usuário e Senha são necessários");
        }

        var userContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userContext));
        var userASP = userManager.Find(email, password);

        if (userASP == null)
        {
            return this.BadRequest("Usuário ou Senha incorretos");
        }

        var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == email).FirstOrDefault();

        if (userASP == null)
        {
            return this.BadRequest("Usuário ou Senha incorretos");
        }

        var userResponse = new UserResponse
        {
            UserId = user.UserId,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            Admin = userManager.IsInRole(userASP.Id, "Admin"),
            Analista = userManager.IsInRole(userASP.Id, "Analista"),
            Parceiro = userManager.IsInRole(userASP.Id, "Parceiro"),
            Vendedor = userManager.IsInRole(userASP.Id, "Vendedor"),
            Financeiro = userManager.IsInRole(userASP.Id, "Financeiro"),
            IsEnabled = user.IsEnabled,
            TinyUserId = user.TinyUserId,
            ConsultorId = user.ConsultorId,
            CampanhaId = user.CampanhaId,

        };
                return Ok(userResponse);
    }
```

Comment: Two different assemblies referenced in your application contain the same namespace and type, which produces ambiguity. You either need to user an alias or type the full namespace of jObject so it knows which assembly you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible causes for this issue:

- 1. You have multiple projects in your solution which use different versions of Newtonsoft.Json
- 2. You have a rogue Newtonsoft.Json dll somewhere in a bin / obj / temporary folder.

Solution:

- 1. If you use Visual Studio then you can use it to see what reference you're using in every project in your solution.
     Check to see which project uses what version of Newtonsoft.Json . You want to only use one, doesn't matter which one as long as you're consistent. Find the lowest version that works in all the projects and use that everywhere. Once you are down to one version of Newtonsoft.Json then you can build again and continue your work.

If you allow your solution to use multiple versions you will keep having issues. When you build a solution, every project is built and resulting dlls, including their other references are copied to whatever destination they are needed. They will even override each other which is what starts another set of issues since a project expects 12.0 for example but gets version 6 instead.

- 2. Start by cleaning the solution, which removes all dlls. Make sure you delete the Bin and Obj Folders everywhere. Then go and clean the Temporary Internet files as well
     This will take care of all accidental versions you might have. It is possible that you have some forgotten dlls somewhere that you don't even know about.

Comment: So in this solution just have this project and I deleted all the dlls from Newtonsoft.Json from the bin, in the debug I didn't have the and in the webconfig I deleted the reference and in the packages too, but this reference error continues
Thanks for helping me, I have this problem right when we started to start the Web Api

Comment: how about the temp files? C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files and also C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: Both appear empty, I even did disk cleaning, I have another application that has the same version of Nuget and works correctly, the only different one among them is the Google api

Comment: Hi Andrei, after doing this process at least 20 times, I managed to correct this error, thanks